# sendind an image URL from servlet to web document

Tags: java, javascript, image, servlets

I'm trying to send an image url to the browswer using javascript and servlet.

I'm doing the following

In html :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../licenta/WebRoot/Scripts/choosebanner.js"></script>
```

In javascript :

```
   window.onload = Onload;

   function OnLoad()
   {
   var requestURI = window.location;

   var resolution = screen.width + 'x' + screen.height;

   var colorDepth = screen.colorDepth;

    var query = '?requestURI=' + encodeURIComponent(requestURI)
          + '&resolution=' + encodeURIComponent(resolution);

    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "<img src ='http://dan-vaio:8080/licenta/  bannerimg.gif'" + query + " width = 500 height = 200 />";
```

}

in servlet:

```
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String requestURI = request.getParameter("requestURI");
String resolution = request.getParameter("resolution");
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
String img = "http://dan-vaio:8080/licenta/advertiser/banners/leader.jpg";
PrintWriter out  = response.getWriter();
out.print(img);
out.close();
```

}

The problem is that i can't get the image to be displayed. Javascript works fine, calls the server, the servers prints the respsone, but the jpg isn't showed in the html page.Any hints on how to get this working ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to deliver the image itself, not its path. Read the image file in the servlet and write the binary to the response. Another way would be to set the src in the javascript to the response of the servlet. But then you need an Ajax call to the servlet, read the response and write it in the img src tag. The way you are doing it, you point the img src to a string and that of course won't display an image.

Comment: Here's the servlet code, in case if anyone needs this :


         `try

 {

 String filePath =  "h:/program files/Workspace/licenta/WebRoot/advertiser/banners/leader.jpg";
 File f = new File(filePath);
 byte[] b = new byte[(int)f.length()];
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
 fis.read(b);
 response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
 ServletOutputStream out  = response.getOutputStream();
 out.write(b);
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }`

Answer (score 0):

It's about your content type. You should set the content type of the response to image/jpeg. This way  your navigator will understand that it's an image. You should change it like this :

```
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
```

That's if you're serving jpeg images, Otherwise please follow this like to find your convenient content type : http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

Comment: True, but only changing the content type does not help if you only send the filepath and not the binary data.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

1. You need to convert image to `FileInputStream`.
2. Then set `response.setContentType("image/jpeg");`

**Example**:

```
FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream("sample.jpg");
response.setContentLength(fileIS.available());
int i = 0;
while ((i = fileIS.read()) != -1) {
  out.write(i);
}
fileIS.close();
```